# Internet Explorer 9 and XSLT

Tags: xslt, internet-explorer-9

I have some javascript code that, based on the browser you're using, applies an XSL transformation to some XML received.  This works in all browsers except IE9.  Although there's a provision in the logic for IE (to use *tranformNode* instead of *new XSLTProcessor()*) it would seem that IE9 does not define transformNode anymore.

I've been searching for some time to see if this is a problem for others without any luck.  Which is puzzling and makes me think I'm doing something terribly wrong.

Here's the code that works with IE7/8 (from jstree - although slightly modified for clarity):

```
xm = document.createElement('xml');
xs = document.createElement('xml');
xm.innerHTML = xml;
xs.innerHTML = xsl;
xm.transformNode(xs.XMLDocument)
```

All I could find regarding IE9 and XSLT is that "it has been changed to be more standards compliant".  I think it was referring to the way that the transformations were done, not so much the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the author of jsTree (which uses XSLT transformations to render XML source data to the tree):

```
if(window.ActiveXObject) {      
   var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate");
   var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument");
   var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument");
   xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
   xslDoc.loadXML(xsl);
   xslt.stylesheet = xslDoc;
   var xslProc = xslt.createProcessor();
   xslProc.input = xmlDoc;
   xslProc.transform();
   callback.call(null, xslProc.output);
   return true;
}
```

http://code.google.com/p/jstree/issues/detail?id=907&q=IE9&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary