# IE 11 compatibility view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-11

My website is broken in IE11. We found that it’s broken due to XSLTProcessor and XPathEvaluator since they are not supported any more in IE. I did some R&D and found that it’s also not supported in IE9 and IE10 but my website is working fine in IE9 and IE10. May I know why it is broken in IE11?

In below screenshot, we can see that document mode is Quirks. Don’t we have same behavior for IE11?
[image]

**EDIT**

We also have meta tag in our master page and it was working fine until IE10 but it’s broken in IE11.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Do we have to use different meta tags for IE11?

Comment: Meta tag has never been reliable.  However, if you do use it, it *MUST* be the first or second tag after the `<head>` (second only to Content-Type meta tag, which must be first if you use one).  The better option is to either add a custom http header in your global.asax or add the custom http header to your iis configuration.

Comment: Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Internet Explorer 9 and XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887607/internet-explorer-9-and-xslt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed meta tag to `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5" />` and it started working fine.